# Recover windows partition after trying guymager

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, usb, hard-drive, gparted

I was trying to learn Ubuntu and the utilities it usually offers (unlike Windows), and I decided to give guymager a try to check on a usb kingston drive I have. When trying it, I decided to use the clone and acquire images to duplicate the usb device. After that, I tried to reboot into my windows drive and it seems the drive is unallocated!

When I rebooted back into Ubuntu, there's a device named 2.0 TB Hard Drive: Kingston (the kingston drive was 8 gb, the windows drive was 2.0 TB). The capacity on this is 8gb.

I tried to use gparted to see what was going on:

[Screenshot]

[image]

Is there a way to recover my windows drive/partition the way it used to be? I'm sorry, I hope the question is ok to be asked here. 
Thank you!